# flutter app crashes on on startup in windows platform

Tags: flutter, runtime-error

I am facing this error while running my newly created flutter app on the [image]windows platform.
can anyone please help me .

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...                                         
Can't load AOT data from C:\Users\janha\Downloads\Compressed\Web_scripting\desktop_app\build\windows\runner\Debug\data\app.so; no such file.
Unable to start engine without AOT data.
Failed to create view controller.
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.
Error launching application on Windows.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use vs2019 this error apears in new version of visual studio

[follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes) install vs2019 then install Desktop development with C++

if you had same error again! delete windows folder and make it again

Comment: didn't help at all

Comment: I had exact problem and solve it in this way, maybe you need to delete all vs and install 2019 @FTFStudio

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I did as the @mohammad esmaili said, but I think that did not work. The flutter windows app Administrator privileges. So I went to the directory that flutters build windows app and runs that app as administrator.. that's it. now the flutter windows app got its privilege so it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio 2022 17.0.6 LTS. No updates, no problems :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This faced the same issue and got it fixed.
Uninstalled visual studio 2022 and installed VS 2019.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).